# "qualunque" and "qualsiasi", are they always interchangeble?

Tags: difference

"Dammi un giornale **qualunque**."
"Farebbe **qualsiasi** lavoro per vivere." Are these two adjective always interchangeable? Can we say, for example:
"Dammi un giornale **qualsiasi**."
"Farebbe **qualunque** lavoro per vivere." I already know that if a concessive phrase contains the present subjunctive of "essere", then "qualunque should be used. Is there any other case where the two adjectives are not interchangeble?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not able to provide neither rules nor references, I can only tell you my opinion:

*Qualunque* and *qualsiasi* both mean *any*, but *qualsiasi* is slightly more *whatever/whichever* (implying a choice), because the etymology is somewhat clearer to Italian ears: "quale si sia". Today we would say "quale che sia", but anyways, *sia* is clearly contained in *qualsiasi*, and is also the reason why you cannot say "qualsiasi sia".

So "dammi un giornale qualunque" means slightly more "give me just any newspaper (I don't care)", while "dammi un giornale qualsiasi" means slightly more "give me whichever newspaper you want to give me".

For the same reason, if I look up in Google "scegliere una carta qualunque", I get 10 results, while if I look up "scegliere una carta qualsiasi" I get about 15800.

In Italy there has been (from 1946 to 1949) a political party called "Fronte dell'Uomo Qualunque" ("Common Man's Front"). It couldn't have been called "Fronte dell'Uomo Qualsiasi", because it didn't refer to a randomly chosen man, but to the common, average man.

As you see, I slightly disagree with [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/qualsiasi-o-qualunque_%28La_grammatica_italiana%29/), and I must say that it's not the first time this happens.